# Are there yajnas that can be done to increase the quality of life and happiness of all people?

Tags: yajna

In Kaliyuga, there is a lot of adharma, so people are becoming more and more sad and because of adharma, we are causing many species of animals to become extinct. Is there any yajna that I can do for the well being of all living beings?

Comment: Sure... many types of soma yaagas

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Please make an answer.

Comment: In Yaksha prashna in Mahabharata, Yudhishtira is asked by Yaksha - *'What is tapasya?'*. Many people think sitting in forest meditating is tapasya, others think doing grand yagna and homa is tapasya. Yudhishtira simply says *'Doing your dharma correctly is tapasya'*. If you are a student, study, if you are a warrior, fight without turning back. if you are a brahmin, do sandhya-vandana, learn vedas, control senses. if you are a merchant, buy/sell goods without cheating.

Comment: @ram But I know for sure that me studying properly will not help other beings. Is there any other tapasya that I can do apart from studying that will also help every beings? Some yajna must be there that will help everyone (it doesn't matter if I do not get the result of the yajna, I pray to Shivji and Ramji everyday so they are already taking care of me).

Comment: @ram or is there a way I can read, say, Rama Raksha Stotram and make the protection of God go from me to everyone else in the world?

Comment: "But I know for sure that me studying properly will not help other beings" - how do you know that ? if you study properly now, you can use that knowledge to help others. if the brahmins were like you and said 'studying is not going to help others', then they would not have learned yagna rituals and they won't be able to perform the homa that you want to do. You HAVE to do YOUR duty. Don't bother about others duty. If you go to a ticket counter and the person behind says 'me giving ticket is not going to help others', then you won't get ticket. everyone must do THEIR OWN job, that itself helps

Comment: @ram but I am giving the ticket and want to help other additionally. Quote me any scripture that says that it is adharma to study and to also help others. I am not forgoing my duty. I am going to study hard and start my own business after education. I am not giving up all my life to doing yajnas for others like you show in your example. Also, if everyone wanted to help everyone, world would be a much better place.

Comment: ok, if you are doing this ABOVE and beyond your duty, that is fine, and appreciatable. In kali yuga, nama sankeertana is the best method, there are many shlokas that back this, since the requirements & restrictions for doing fruitful yagna are very hard to maintain. If you know vishnu sahasranama, you can chant that (don't utter pranava mantra(om) in the dhyana shlokas before 'vishvam vishnu..' and after '..sarva praharanayudah' if you don't have upanayana). doing every day for one mandala (48 days) is great tapasya.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94322/discussion-between-shashwat-asthana-and-ram).

Comment: Without proper guidance, if you try to teach these to others, you will only further suffer in life!!!!

Comment: @Shashwat there's a saying that first "you learn to swim before teaching" (you doesnt mean you. Its a saying). First you do your duty, you purify yourself from all Karmas, you remove all negative dark energies in you first. Follow that method. Then after you attain, a happy life after removing all sadness, then with proper guidance teach others. You need equip yourself mentally in knowing how to teach others, what sort of eligibilty is necessary etc. Simply by doing some practices and asking others to do, you will only lose your tapa shakti!!!

Comment: @AkshayS I do not know anything compared to some people  in this website, so I will not teach anyone (Also, who will learn from a 16 year old lol). My question is different from what you are thinking.

Comment: @Shashwat: In my opinion the word "Yajna" is to be defined properly in the question. The word yajna (Sanskrit: यज्ञ; yajña) has its root in the Sanskrit yaj meaning "to worship, adore, honor, revere" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajna).  In Rigveda, Yajurveda (itself a derivative of this root) and others, it means "worship, devotion to anything, prayer and praise, an act of worship or devotion, a form of offering or oblation, and sacrifice".  Are you expecting  answer indicating any type of worship or only  offerings into a sacred fire, as shown in movies?

Comment: @Shashwat Its just a guidance from my side to apply when you grow further!!!

Comment: @AkshayS Thank you for giving me guidance in such matters. I will try to always remember this.

Comment: @Shashwat personally I have seen my relatives who do some poojas get benefits and recommend to others without proper guidance. In 48 days, they have suffered bad Karma for it....So your focus should be on to how you should be good and wise and follow methods that removes all your past Karmas and change your destiny and have a future of fortunes through grace of Brahman. That should be in your eyes!

Comment: @Shashwat there are many types of yajnas i already listed in answer elsewhere. The purpose of yajna would be your sankalp. So this is where you decide and visualize your goal of performing the action. This applies to every ritual. Vedic and agamic rituals can be  used

Answer (score 1):

All Yajñas by definition have a universal component but the specific utility of the yajña depends on one's sankalpa. So if you wish to sponsor a universal yajña it can be Bhagavad Gītā mahā yajña in which ahutis are offered with each verse of the Bhagavad Gītā.

Comment: Where is Bhagavad Gita Maha Yajna mentioned in the scriptures? Is there only Bhagavad Gita Maha yajna or there are maha yajna for other Gitas also?